# When to detect collisions in game loop

Tags: collision-detection, game-loop, timing

My game loop uses a fixed time step to do "physics" updates, say every 20 ms. In here I move objects. I draw frames as frequently as possible. I work out a value between 0 and 1 to represent the proportion of the physics tick that is complete and interpolate between the previous and current physics state before drawing. It results in a smoother game assuming the frame rate is higher than the physics update rate.

I am currently doing the collision detection in the physics update routine. I was wondering should it instead take place in the interpolated draw routine where the positions match what the user sees? Collisions can result in explosions by the way.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're using an approach similar to what this article describes [Fix Your Timestep!](http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/). I suggest that you don't mix your physics/collision with rendering; do the collision in update like you are right now. That interpolated state is an **approximation** simply used for smoother rendering. Even if you check for collision on interpolated state, it will not help with visuals.

Here is an example (partially taken from comments of that article):

Suppose you follow this scheme in each time step of physics engine:

1. Integrate
2. Test for collisions
3. Respond to collisions

Consider a ball bouncing off wall forming V shape path and collision is detected/resolved on second time step:

1. Ball is before collision, visually ball is at left side of the V path
2. Ball collides with wall, collision resolved, ball has now bounced off and is on right side of the V

Linearly interpolate between these 2 states and you'll be rendering the ball somewhere in the middle of the V path making the collision path seem flatter. Checking collision at the interpolated state will yield no collision and thus will not help in correcting the visuals. Only way to improve visuals here is to make time steps smaller.

Comment: Assuming 50 per second and 75 frames per second: the interpolated values are more fine grained. Wouldn't that help in producing a better result for collision testing?

Comment: 50 updates per sec and 75 renders per sec?

Comment: Sorry. Yes exactly what I meant.

Comment: I could wrong but the interpolation is just an approximation and will not yield collisions. Can you specify visible defects that you're experiencing or what motivates you to do this extra collision checking on interpolated state?

Comment: It's not that there are defects, I just want to do it right. My thinking was that the approximated value is what we use for drawing  which is what the user sees and therefore is the correct value to use for collisions.

Comment: My advice remains the same: that extra collision check will not yield any collisions and thus will not improve visuals. You can try it out if you want, or maybe someone else will correct me if my logic was flawed in the ball example I gave above.

Comment: I'll revisit this after giving it some time for further opinions or when I have some empirical results. I'm surprised there is only one answer. It seems a fundamental question.

Comment: @Ciaran Imho, the question is answered. Unless you're not using continued collision detection. Basically, you set the velocities for all objects, then check if at any point of an objects path, that object would collide with another object. If any collide, move both objects to the time of collision and update their velocities (and/or handle the collision). Then, if they still have a certain distance to move during this physics frame, check for collisions again, then move them to their end position (unless there's another collision). After doing this, you're at physics frame t2. Then, render.

Comment: At this point we get back to the V-shaped path example in the answer: interpolating between the balls position p(t1) at t1 (before physics & collisions) and at t2 (after physics and collisions) will result in the ball moving in a straight line from p(t1) to p(t2). The tip of the V, which is also the point of the collision, will not be reached. As has been pointed out in the answer, this effect can be reduced by choosing smaller timesteps.

Comment: @sarahm I don't see it as an option for me to check for collisions in the way you describe. I am intersecting polygons with other polygons. I do it based on a computed position rather than a prediction along a path (that's the part I imagine would be too difficult). If I am wrong and there is a good reference for your technique perhaps you could let me know.

Comment: [Real Time Collision Detection](http://www.amazon.com/Real-Time-Collision-Detection-Interactive-Technology/dp/1558607323) goes into some detail on continuous collision detection (and, in general, is a great resource for collision detection). See also http://www.wildbunny.co.uk/blog/2011/04/20/collision-detection-for-dummies/ for a short overview over CCD. Basically, it boils down to minowski sums and some simplifications, but the topic is still to large to explain it in a comment.